# Lock size of some master shape children

Tags: microsoft-visio, shapes, microsoft-visio-2016

I am trying to make a master shape which allows me to lock the size of some of its children.

The specific example is to create a border to a square as seen in the [attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvkJB.png).

The issue I am encountering is that when you add a master shape to a document all the width and sizes of the children etc become a formula based off the whole master shapes size `BeginX: =Sheet.489!Width*0.9875`

Because the sizes of the children is a formula based of the width of the parent master shape any protection doesn't actually work.

What I specifically want to do is when you resize the square the border will remain the same size and not scale. Just for the sides to grow longer.

Im wondering is there a way to actually fix the size + position of some of the child elements to do this?
Please help :D

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. All you need to do is to edit the master shape using **Open Group**.
Use the shape explorer window to find the sub-shape and open this sub-shape's shapesheet. You will now see the formula in the Height and Width cells.
You can toggle the display to show Values or Formula from the right-click menu. Look at the value to check it is the value you want the shape to take. Now go back to the formula and if, say, you want the Width value to be 15mm then set the Width formula to be:
=GUARD(15mm)